# Bootstrap Nesting with right alignment rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nested, alignment

Creating a frontpage for a takeout restaurant.

The problem i am having is that the last row won't fit inside because of a double height element.

Code

```html
<div class="row">
  <a class="col-md-3 img-box img-hover" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x900">
  </a>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <a class="col-md-4 img-box img-hover" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x600">
      </a>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
          <a class="col-md-6 img-box img-hover" href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
          </a>
          <a class="col-md-6 img-box img-hover" href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <a class="col-md-6 img-box img-hover" href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
          </a>
          <a class="col-md-6 img-box img-hover" href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x600">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a class="col-md-4 img-box img-hover" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
      </a>
      <a class="col-md-4 img-box img-hover" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot of problem

[image]

How can I fit the last 2 elements on the same row as the rest?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bootply.com/KSRUmHINHw

You need to use nested grid rows with this. So the second column is really  made up of two rows.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x175"></div></div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x25"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x175"></div></div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x25"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x200"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the rows differently. Think of the two rows on the left, as one group, and the double height item on the right, as a second group. They are both on the same row.

```html
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="img-box img-hover" href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x600">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="img-box img-hover" href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
        </a>
        <a class="img-box img-hover" href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="img-box img-hover" href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="img-box img-hover" href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a class="img-box img-hover" href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x300">
    </a>
    <a class="img-box img-hover" href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/480x600">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen live example: http://codepen.io/narxx/pen/vGbzvR

Comment: For a minute there i thought this was the solution.. The problem is the first block being 480x900 (3 blocks tall) making your solution create a new problem. :(

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. Must have missed that when rewriting your whole thing :) I have another question, the two right columns have only 600 pixels height, as the two on the left have 900 pixels height. Where do you want to have the spare spaces? On the bottom of the two right columns?